# Retrieve data between certain hours of day

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query to retrieve data between midnight and 7am of the current day.  I know I am on the right track but cannot get the syntax correct...

```
SELECT * FROM `monthly`
WHERE LogDateTime >= date_sub(curdate('07:00:00'),INTERVAL 1 hour)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CURDATE()` for start and add 7 hours for the end of the datetime of `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT * FROM `monthly`
WHERE LogDateTime BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() +  INTERVAL 7 hour
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a5qxnNwYcrAWuvNnDzJAai/1).

Comment: Yes that works.  How could I edit it to get 7am yesterday to 7am today?  I tried `WHERE LogDateTime BETWEEN (CURDATE() + INTERVAL -1 day, 7 hour) AND (CURDATE() +  INTERVAL 7 hour)` but it's not right...

Comment: Try: `LogDateTime - INTERVAL 7 hour BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 day AND CURDATE()` or `LogDateTime BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 day + INTERVAL 7 hour AND CURDATE() +  INTERVAL 7 hour`

Comment: Forpas, one more, I'll create a new question if you need me too...the end goal of this is two take two values, one that occurs at 7am on day 1 and one that occurs at 7am on day 2, and subtract from each other.  How can I write it so I only return those two rows (and not every minute in between)?

Comment: For this you must provide sample data and expected results to clarify, so it's better to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    monthly
WHERE 
    LogDateTime <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 HOUR)
AND
    LogDateTime >= CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this one:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM 
    monthly
WHERE 
    LogDateTime <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 9 HOUR)
AND
    LogDateTime >= CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read a bit about how to filter data and some build in functions too. Just in case you are using MySQL then you code will be as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM monthly
WHERE LogDateTime between CURDATE() and DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 HOUR)
```

Here i am using built-in MySQL function **CURDATE** and **DATE_ADD**. Please note that it will include both the upper and lower limits.

Following are some references for you:

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-curdate/

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-between/

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-where/

Just a small comment thought not related to your question, you should not be using * for selecting columns. Using * is not recommended at all. You better write each and every column name in your SELECT statement